# Windows 8 AMD catalyst 14.4 display adapter

Tags: windows-8, drivers, display, graphics-card

I have AMD radeon r7 260x graphics card and a Asrock H61M-GS motherboard. The problem at the moment is that in device manager only display adapter drivers that appear are:

Intel(R) HD graphics

Intel(R) HD graphics (Microsoft Corporation - 1.2)

Microsoft basic display adapter.

So after I booted my computer up and updated the OS (Windows 8 64bit) and with one of my monitors connected to the motherboard since the graphics card wasn´t working, I noticed that there was a Intel HD options when I right clicked the desktop and it was for some Intel HD graphics stuff. Then I tried installing Amd catalyst install manager and first I got error it could not complete then some question mark and the view log showed this:

''Existing packages

AMD Catalyst Install Manager

HydraVision

Packages for install

AMD Catalyst Install Manager

Final Status: Success

Version of Item: 8.0.916.0

Size: 20 Mbytes

Other detected devices

Error messages ''

That was the Amd catalyst 14.4 for windows 8 64bit, I also tried some beta version Amd catalyst 14.9
which didn´t show any errors or problems but still got no progress with any adapters or graphics drivers.

I´ve watched youtube videos and read too many forums posts and nothing is happening.

I tried completely uninstalling both the amd stuff and the display adapted and install all that again in
different orders and so on. Honestly I´m totally defeated by this crap and none of this was a problem before with changing my harddrive and installing windows 8 again. Then the drivers just worked instantly and there never any issues.

Comment: Please upload a picture. Since you don't have enough reputations here, upload it some where else and provide the link here.

Comment: Those will be up sometime tomorrow. When I´m back from school.

Comment: use DDU to remove all AMD drivers: http://www.wagnardmobile.com/DDU/. Remember to make a backup of Windows before you try this.

Comment: Very later response but here are some [pictures](http://imgur.com/a/kq7fJ)

Comment: Download IOBit Driver Booster, install it and it will perform an automatic scan. After the scan look whether it listed an update for AMD. If yes just download the update. It will be installed automatically. Check whether your problems got solved after this.

Comment: Found a fix and a huge apology for wasting your time. Seems the after taking out my rams and gpu and cleaning my computer when reassembling the computer store guy he forgot to properly close the lower white pin on the ram slot so it got in the way of the gpu being properly connected. Hardware issue solved but wasted your time and a lot of mine. I´m never trusting someone else to reassemble my computer again.